# NHibernate: Best way to map to DateTime a value stored in a non-standard way

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, mapping

I am just getting started with NHibernate (for the 15th time it would seem) and am having the following problem.

The following table:

```
Table Facility
Column FACILITY_ID integer
Column NAME varchar2(50)
Column MONTH varchar2(5)
```

For whatever reason, month is a string instead of a native Date type and looks like this:

```
"200811" represents 11/01/2008
"200307" represents 07/01/2003
you get the idea
```

I would like to map it to the following class

```
public class Facility {
  int Id {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}
  DateTime Month {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to map the MONTH column to the Month property but don't quite know how to approach the situation.  Obviously, I could have a protected property string MonthString and have the Month property Parse that column, but that seems icky.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: I would alter the database table when your application is the only one using the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution may be to use a [custom value type](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom).

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify your database schema, the answer is `IUserType`.  [Here is a good write-up](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype.aspx).

There are many extension points that can help you solve complex problems in NHibernate.  The most useful extension point is IUserType.